# How can I forward UDP packets to the browser (node.js? webRTC? other?) while processing it on the way there?

Tags: node.js, html, sockets, udp, webrtc

I want to send and later display a video in the browser. I have the application that takes the video from my camera and converts it to bytes, later on - it sends it through UDP to a specific port. 
Now - I have the node.js script that receives already the bytes:

```
var PORT            = 19777;
var MULTICAST_GROUP = "224.0.0.251";

var dgram = require("dgram");
var payload = new Buffer('A wild message appears');
var client = dgram.createSocket("udp4");

client.on("message", function(message, rinfo) {
    console.log("received: ",message,rinfo);
});
client.on("listening", function() {
    console.log("listening on ",client.address());

    client.setBroadcast(true);
    client.setTTL(64);
    client.setMulticastTTL(64);
    client.setMulticastLoopback(true);
    client.addMembership(MULTICAST_GROUP);
    client.send(payload, 0, payload.length, PORT, MULTICAST_GROUP, function(err,bytes) {
        console.log("err: "+err+" bytes: "+bytes);
        // client.close();
    });
});
client.on("close", function() {
    console.log("closed");
});
client.on("error", function(err) {
    console.log("error: ",err);
});
client.bind(19777);
```

and after running that - I see the packets in the console.

I need to process each packet (e.g. check whether it is from the current frame) - which hopefully generates the video stream on the other site - and - somehow - send it to the client's browser. At this point I don't even know how to process the packets itself - where and how are they stored after receiving them, if I can send it later to the browser, how to play it in the browser (html5?), etc...

I'm a total beginner when it comes to node.js and similar, so I've read a lot during last hours and I found an [article that recommends Kaazing WebSocket Gateway](https://matthiaswessendorf.wordpress.com/2011/03/21/extending-tcp-udp-to-the-browser/), but I'm not sure if it's still an acceptable standard for that. Also, I found the [webRTC](https://bitbucket.org/webrtc/codelab), but I'm not sure if I can use it with custom stream (since I'm not using any popular video codects).

Could anyone give me any hint how to process now? I found some [stackoverflow previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190028/node-js-listen-for-udp-and-forward-to-connected-http-web-clients), but the solution provided there is no longer online.. I'm lost in that completely and I will appreciate any help from you guys,
thanks!

Comment: `WebRTC` is probably not what you are searching for. You could use `WebSocket` and `MediaSource` along with a custom `SourceBuffer`, but I don't know if that works.

Comment: "since I'm not using any popular video codects" What do you mean by this, you need to use codecs to get anywhere near a stable framerate on the remote. You don't choose which codec you actually use, you just provide some options and through negotiations between client one of them is picked and used.