# how to transfer data received from UDP to the webpage in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, udp

I'm running the two apps from [here](https://gist.github.com/ciaranj/9056285). So we have a client:

```
var PORT = 5007 ;
  var dgram = require('dgram');
  var client = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

  client.on('listening', function () {
      var address = client.address();
      console.log('UDP Client listening on ' + address.address + ":" + address.port);
      client.setBroadcast(true)
      client.setMulticastTTL(128); 
      client.addMembership('224.1.1.1');
  });

  client.on('message', function (message, remote) {   
      console.log('A: Epic Command Received. Preparing Relay.');
      console.log('B: From: ' + remote.address + ':' + remote.port +' - ' + message);
  });

  client.bind(PORT);
```

and a server:

```
var PORT = 5007 ;
  var dgram = require('dgram');
  var client = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

  client.on('listening', function () {
      var address = client.address();
      console.log('UDP Client listening on ' + address.address + ":" + address.port);
      client.setBroadcast(true)
      client.setMulticastTTL(128); 
      client.addMembership('224.1.1.1');
  });

  client.on('message', function (message, remote) {   
      console.log('A: Epic Command Received. Preparing Relay.');
      console.log('B: From: ' + remote.address + ':' + remote.port +' - ' + message);
  });

  client.bind(PORT);
```

It works pretty well, when I run it in two separates consoles - I see the transfer is going and the messages appear on both sites. Now, how can I display/transfer all this data to any webpage?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends on what *type* of data it is combined with if you want it to be real-time or served upon request.

If you want it to be served upon request, you'd have to store the data somewhere so it can be accessed at a later point. Either on the filesystem or in something like [MongoDB's GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/), or either directly in a database (as I said, depending on what type of data it is)

If you want it to be streamed real-time to connected web clients you'd have to use something like [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) or [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/). The difference between the two are significant. Socket.io is simple to work with but requires a man-in-the-middle server whereas WebRTC (Web Real-Time Communications) is directly peer-to-peer in the browser and a lot harder to work with. WebRTC is fairly new and isn't available in older browser versions, so I'd suggest going with Socket.io or similar in this case.

Hopefully you get a better overview on the possibilities you have. Either way you need to catch the data somewhere between the two clients (as shown in your client-server example)

Comment: Thank you, I found this (question)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190028/node-js-listen-for-udp-and-forward-to-connected-http-web-clients], but the answer is already gone unfortunatelly (the code on external webpage)... I see that this user had exactly the same question/problem that I have - I also stuck on passing the value to the browser. Could you help me with that, maybe there is some simple working example, or sth? I would really appreciate your help, thank you very much